# Receiving response from python as an array - PHP

Tags: python, webautomation, playwright, playwright-python

I have PHP code, and I'm calling python script which takes the URL, go the web URL, takes the JSON page and then send back JSON page to the PHP code, but the issue is that i got that JSON in the array and not in the correct JSON format, anu help?

python code:

```
import json
import sys
import bs4
import urllib.parse
link = urllib.parse.unquote(sys.argv[1])
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36')
    page = context.new_page()
    cookie_file = open('./cookies.json')
    cookies = json.load(cookie_file)
    context.add_cookies(cookies)
    try:
        page.goto(link)
        page.wait_for_timeout(10000)
        print(page.content())
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()      
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in playwright script.")
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()
```

Comment: What does "i got that JSON in the array and not in the correct JSON format" mean?

Comment: Put `page.content()` in a variable and then use `json.loads()` to parse it.

Comment: Why don't you just download the file instead of navigating to it?

Comment: @hardkoded how do you mean?

Comment: @Barmar i did and ive got the error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1

Comment: @liol Use the `requests` library instead of `playwright`

Comment: That means the contents of the page isn't JSON. What's the URL?

Comment: @Barmar i can not get page source with the requests module, thats why i use playwright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `content` function relies on `document.documentElement.outerHTML`, so you might get a formatted value.
If the request returns a `JSON` you could grab the text from the `response` that `goto` returns:

```
response = page.goto("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/corysimmons/colors.json/master/colors.json")
jsonContent = response.text()
jsonResult = json.loads(jsonContent)
print(jsonResult)
```

If there is some processing in the middle, you could ask for the `inner_text` of the `:root` element:

```
jsonContent = page.inner_text(':root')
jsonResult = json.loads(jsonContent)
print(jsonResult)
```